# Table and Figure Caption Citation Problem

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions

When I build a LaTeX code, the references to figures and tables labels are not recognized, so latex builder prints "?" in the place. And simplifying the entire text I found out that even the simple dummy document

```
\documentclass{book}
  \begin{document}
    Some text cites Table \cite{whatever}

  \begin{table}[h]
    \caption{my caption}\label{whatever}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
      Text
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

generates this:

> Some text cites Table [?]
>
> Table 1: my caption
>
> Text

I'm using MiKTeX 2.4-64 for a couple of months, but I do not remember getting this type of errors with past versions MiKTeX versions. Would someone have a clue on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After processing your document, you will receive the following warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `whatever' on page 1 undefined on input line 3.
```

which gives you a hint about the cause of the problem: you are using `\cite` and you should be using `\ref` instead (the output `[?]` also indicates that a citation was incorrectly expected). Simply replace:

```
Some text cites Table \cite{whatever}
```

with

```
Some text cites Table~\ref{whatever}
```

`\cite` is for bibliographical citations.

Comment: I get `[?]` for a missing bibliography entry and `??` for a missing label. Maybe you could include that as a hint for diagnosis.

Comment: Oh yes, what a mistake of mine! You are totally right, thank you.